# Efficiently replace vstack + concatenate applied to numpy arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy

The last two lines in the block below are repeated millions of times in my actual code:

```
import numpy as np

# Data with proper shape
N1, N2 = 3, 5
aa = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (23, 2000))
a1 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N1)
a2 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N2)

# Replace these two lines as efficiently as possible
a3 = np.vstack(np.concatenate((a1, a2, a1, a2)))
aa[:(N1 + N2 + N1 + N2)] = aa[:(N1 + N2 + N1 + N2)] + a3
```

Combining `np.vstack()` with `np.concatenate()` to then add the result to a section of the array seems less than optimal.

Is there a better, ie: *more efficient*, way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.concatenate()` and a simple *broadcasting*:

```
In [18]: np.concatenate((a1, a2, a1, a2))[:,None]
```

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, broadcasting is almost always faster than functions.